# How to open a file from command line using canopen

Tags: c, file, file-io

Look at this code

```
/* A file can be opened for reading or not  Page 547 KN KING*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Input to this program in command line is => canopen file_name */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: Canopen filename\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s cant be opened\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%s can be opened\n", argv[1]);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

How to open a file using this program. I have saved it as 'canopen.c'. The book which I am learning from gives a syntax like this:

```
canopen filename
```

But when I migrate to this directory from terminal and key in the above command where filename is replaced by file called 'example.dat' the bash shell throws out a message 
`'canopen: command not found'`

How to open this file? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to compile your `.c` file into an executable binary.

Depending on your current OS, it will require something in lines of:

```
cc -o canopen canopen.c
```

or

```
gcc -o canopen canopen.c
```

That will produce a binary called `canopen` in your current directory.

To execute it, you'll need to try prepending binary with `./` to refer to the current directory, if your OS is Unix-like:

```
./canopen filename
```

Comment: OMG! But i compiled it using codeblocks and there was no seperate O/P file for this file. Every o/p file was created from main, since i wrote every program in main.c. I will try it out, just a minute.

Comment: I'm not sure what codeblocks is (I assume it's some IDE?), but the examples I gave are IDE-independent and can be issued just from your bash command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Can you let me know how to submit output files to codejam, or submit solutions to codejam?

Comment: Yeah IDE.I issued it from bash command line and its working thanks a lot

Comment: I have never participated in codejam, I'm sorry (if you're referring to Google CodeJam).

Comment: For codereview, there's codereview.stackexchange.com, but one obvious thing is `if(argc != 2)` if you will call the program as `./canopen asdf asdf asdf` it will bypass this condition, not sure whether this is what you want :) And if you won't supply filename at all, it will produce unwanted results as well :)

Comment: @user1971996: SO isn't really a chat website man :) But for about 20 years now.